# Can we have app-assign ip address in a multitenant App Service Deployment?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, firewall

Can we have an app assign ip address in a multitenant App Service Deployment?

Would that allow us to access app service by IP Address?

The goal is to use this static IP so a client can add it to his firewall

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can we have an app assign Ip address in a multitenant App Service
> Deployment would that allow us to access app service by IP Address?

According to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info#app-assigned-ip-addresses) Assigning an IP address to an app is only possible with an external deployment, and when IP-based TLS/SSL binding is configured.

In a multitenant App Service deployment, ***you cannot assign IP addresses to individual apps,*** but you can use the default IP address of the App Service to access your app.

[image]

While creating web App it is assigned a public virtual IP address. App Service makes outbound calls outside of the virtual network topology, the outbound address that is used public VIP of the App Service none of these connections are routed down a VPN.

If you want to access your app service by IP address You can use the public VIP address of the App Service. You can find this IP address in properties like below:

[image]

References:

[Networking considerations - Azure App Service Environment | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info)

[Secure a custom DNS with a TLS/SSL binding - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings)

Comment: thanks for the reply mate. I've to confirm a few things you say here because I've posted this at sometime ago and I was able to succeed to have a multitenant deployment with App service working behind a single IP address. What I did was to set the application to have an app assigned ip address, but then because I did not know better at the time, I put a application gateway in front of it and used its address instead of the app service. In order to proper reply to you I should try to access the app service not with the application gateway ip but with the app service ip.

Comment: It should work even with just the app assigned IP but the tricky thing is that we should always send the host name on the request because the IP address is not enough for azure to properly route the request to our service. give me some days to review this and I'll give feedback again (I'm a little bit busy right now)